# Error en la llamada a un método dentro de una clase

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Quiero llamar a *init* desde fuera de la clase *Base*, pero tengo un queryselector que me da el siguiente error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined**

```
class Base {
    constructor(el) {
        this.DOM = { el: el };
    }

    init() {
        this.title = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.content');
        console.log('Hi');
    }
};

let base = new Base();
base.init();
```

Aqui la prueba : https://jsfiddle.net/Lgohgeqb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Porque le estás diciendo que tome en el constructor el elemento pero nunca lo declaraste, además debería ser [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
Entonces debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
class Base {
    init() {
        this.title = document.querySelector('.content');
        console.log('Hi');
    }
};

let base = new Base();
base.init();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El tema es que necesito el constructor, quizá no he puesto un buen ejemplo. Este es el proyecto en el que estoy trabajando https://github.com/codrops/OutdoorsTemplate/blob/master/js/main.js , necesito llamar a init desde fuera de la clase Entry.